# systemd-nspawn/machinectl and macvlan

Tags: systemd-nspawn, macvlan

I would like to create a nspawn container connected to the network via macvlan and dhcp. All documentation I have found were very instructive but did not offer a step by step procedure for this setup.

What I did so far was to create the container (debian base) using debootstrap including systemd-container:

```
debootstrap --arch=armhf --include=systemd-container stretch /var/lib/machines/raspbian-09 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian
```

**Native host network**

running:

```
systemd-nspawn -b -M raspbian-09
```

or

```
machinectl raspbian-09
```

with the unit file /etc/systemd/nspawn/raspbian-09.nspawn
containing:

```
[Exec]
Boot=true
PrivateUsers=no

[Network]
Private=no
VirtualEthernet=no
```

In both cases, the network connection is fine.

**Macvlan**

For the macvlan, I either run the command:

```
systemd-nspawn -b -M raspbian-09 --network-macvlan=eth0
```

or

```
machinectl raspbian-09
```

with the unit file /etc/systemd/nspawn/raspbian-09.nspawn containing:

```
[Exec]
Boot=true
PrivateUsers=no

[Network]
MACVLAN=eth0
```

In both cases, the connection to the network does not work.

Within the container, I can see that an interface mv-eth0 is created:

```
# networkctl
IDX LINK             TYPE               OPERATIONAL SETUP     
  1 lo               loopback           carrier     unmanaged 
  2 mv-eth0          ether              degraded    configuring
```

however, there is no ipv4 address:

```
# ip a
mv-eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

What other configurations on the host and container should be made?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is the following:

All the following actions are to be done in the container.

Check if your container is using systemd-networkd, you can check if that is the case by running the following command

```
systemctl status systemd-networkd
```

If the service is not enabled and not running, you will need to enable and start it

```
systemctl enable systemd-networkd
systemctl start systemd-networkd
```

You may also need to enable and start the systemd-resolved service, if it is not enabled and started.

```
systemctl enable systemd-resolved
systemctl start systemd-resolved
```

If you need a dynamic ipv4 address created for you on your macvlan interface, you can then create the network setup file `/etc/systemd/network/mveth0.network`, with the following contents

```
[Match]
Name=mv-eth0

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
```

If you need to set a static ipv4 address for the macvlan interface. For example if you have a gateway address 192.168.1.1, and need to set the ipv4 address to 192.168.1.14/24, you can then use the following content for the network setup file `/etc/systemd/network/mveth0.network`.

```
[Match]
Name=mv-eth0

[Network]
IPForward=yes
Address=192.168.1.14/24
Gateway=192.168.1.1
# DNS= ?
```

After creating the file you will need to restart the systemd-networkd service

```
systemctl restart systemd-networkd
```

You may need to use sudo in your case to run the commands